# How to load some images before executing a function

Tags: javascript, image, promise, srcset

I have an image slider that is positioned outside the viewport initially, and then slides in. I want this to happen when the first three images are loaded, otherwise the user sees the images downloading as the slider is moving into viewport.

I tried preloading the images using promises, but the images are not preloading and the slider init function runs in parallel with the image download.

The images have this kind of structure:

```html
<img srcset="
  https://www.datocms-assets.com/portrait.jpg?w=600&amp;auto=format 600w,
  https://www.datocms-assets.com/portrait.jpg?w=900&amp;auto=format 900w,
  https://www.datocms-assets.com/portrait.jpg?w=1200&amp;auto=format 1200w" 
  sizes="(min-width: 400px) 80vw, (min-width: 700px) 75vmin, 100vw" 
  src="https://www.datocms-assets.com/portrait.jpg?w=900&amp;auto=format"
/>
```

The script:

```js
const loadImage = path => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.srcset = path;
    img.onload = () => resolve();
  });
};

const sliderEl = document.querySelector('.slider');

const firstImages = Array.from(sliderEl.querySelectorAll('img'))
  .filter((item, i) => i < 3)
  .map(image => image.src);

const loadImg = (...paths) => Promise.all(paths.map(loadImage));
loadImg(...firstImages).then(initSlider(sliderEl));
```

EDIT: You can see the site here https://photography-blog.netlify.com/. The problem seems to appear on most browsers except Chrome, and during the first visit when the photos are not cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue maybe related to the fact that the URI https://www.datocms-assets.com/portrait.jpg is returning a 404.

If that is indeed the case, you should also consider the `onerror` callback in the `loadImage` method:

```
const loadImage = path => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.srcset = path;
    img.onload = () => resolve();
    img.onerror = () => resolve();
  });
};
```

Comment: The URIs are not the real ones, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: So, can you provide more information (complete HTML, console logs, etc) so that we can reproduce the issue you are facing?